# Dynamic event on dynamically created button - ASP.net (unable to print "Hello World" message)

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" visible="True">
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Height="29px" Width="950px" style="margin-left: 24px">
            <asp:Button   ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="createtb"  Text="+" />
        </asp:Panel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button bb = new Button();
        bb.Text = "Buttoninpageload";
        this.Panel2.Controls.Add(bb);
        bb.Click += new EventHandler(bb_Click);
    }

    protected void bb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("IN BB_Click");
    }

    protected void createtb(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button bt = new Button();
        bt.Text = "buttonincreatetb";

        this.Panel2.Controls.Add(bt);

        bt.Click += new EventHandler(bt_Click);
    }

    public void bt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("Hello world"); 
    }
}
```

Dynamic event on dynamically created ASP.net button; I'm unable to print "Hello World" message

Kindly provide some solution as soon as possible.

Comment: `Response.Write` is not what you think it is. It is the full response from the server to the client (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525585(v=vs.90).aspx). Decide where you want to print your message, create a control there (eg a label), and then update the content in the control with your message

Comment: label is also not showing after button click @Jonathan

Comment: I don't see a label in your markup or code behind. Please update your code with label. It should work ;)

Comment: @Jonathan I want to create a label dynamically by clicking the dynamically created button

Public void bt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Label ll = new Label();
        ll.Text = "Label one";
        Panel2.Controls.Add(ll);

    }

Answer (score 0):

Problem is `postback` here. In your `createtb` handler you are creating button and attaching handler `bt_Click` and in handler writing to `Response` stream `Response.Write("Hello world");` but when you click on that button it makes a postback request and in `page_load` event you are creating another button whose handler writes `Response.Write("IN BB_Click");`. You should change your `Pahe_Load` using `IsPostBack` property like below. So that, the dynamic button will be created only when page loads for first time.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(!IsPostBack) {
    Button bb = new Button();
    bb.Text = "Buttoninpageload";
    this.Panel2.Controls.Add(bb);
    bb.Click += new EventHandler(bb_Click);
  }
}
```

Comment: but still not able to print "Hello World"